# Where can I find Default.aspx.cs file after deploying the asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, reverse-engineering

I accidentally deleted an asp.net solution from my PC.  I need to recover it. I tried to use every File recovery softwares out there but none of them was able to recover it.

However the website is deployed on a server. So I was able to get the binary dll from the wwwroot folder and the aspx files. I also have the deployement package that I used to publish it.

I used [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile the dll, I recovered all the classes. However only thing left is the Code Behind Default.aspx.cs. It was not available in the dll I got from the deployment.

After some research I found out it is created at runtime in the

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyProject\
```

there is a file called `default.aspx.cdcab7d2` with a `.compile` extension

I open it in notepad and this is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preserve resultType="3" virtualPath="/MyProject/Default.aspx" hash="d32ddda84" filehash="5c7767628c373188" flags="110000" assembly="App_Web_wcetn4cy" type="ASP.default_aspx">
    <filedeps>
        <filedep name="/MyProject/Default.aspx" />
        <filedep name="/MyProject/Site.Master" />
    </filedeps>
 </preserve>
```

So I get the `App_Web_wcetn4cy` and decompile it with dotpeek, I get a cs file but it is some sort of autogenerated file and not the code behind I had.

Any idea where I can get the Code behind file Default.aspx.cs ?

Thanks

Comment: All code behinds should be together; Default.aspx is not a special page that uses some other convention.  It should be compiled with all of the other ASPX page code behinds.  Also, I'd highly recommend putting the project in source control; it's free through tfs.visualstudio.com.

Comment: @BrianMains that's the only code behind I have. I only have one page. I was able to recover all the classes but not the code behind, any idea where the location is? Thanks

Comment: It should be in a DLL if you are using a compiled application (like web application project template, which I assume you are).  You could also look for the DLL in temporary internet files...

Comment: If it's not in the DLL, then it wasn't compiled at all. That either means that there wasn't any code behind to begin with (it inherits some other class), or it's in the filesystem (using `src=...` instead of `codebehind=...`).

Answer (score 0):

Decompile the corresponding dll you will get all the Code behind files using .NET REFLECTOR TOOL